# Backbone: navigation callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

***What I have:***

I navigate through backbone's views via `Backbone.history.navigate("someFragment", {trigger: true})` method

***What I want:***

I'm searching for correct way to pass navigation callback function. Means something like `Backbone.history.navigate("someFragment", {trigger: true}, callbackFunction)`. Important point - I want that callback proceeds ONLY ONCE, and when I call `Backbone.history.navigate("someFragment", {trigger: true})` next time, it won't be proceeded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should listen to the `route` event of your router.

```
myRouter.on('route:someFragment', callbackFunction )
```

To create a one-time callback you could use underscore's [`once`](http://underscorejs.org/#once):

```
var oneTimeCallback = _.once( callbackFunction );
myRouter.on('route:someFragment', oneTimeCallback )
```

Comment: thanks, is this guaranteed to fire only after the router finishes the navigation call or could it happen during?

Comment: @pawel do you have to specify the fragment? What if I only sort of know what it will be?